# Give out all class properties

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, info

I was just wondering how I could give out everything that is in NSDictionary *info:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Just to see whats in it. Is there a simple way?

Regars, Philip

Comment: What does `Give out everything` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do:

```
NSLog( @"info dictionary is %@", info );
```

in your code.

Passing "`info`" to NSLog is the same as doing "`[info description]`", you print out the entire contents (keys and values of your dictionary).

Comment: if only everything was that easy.

Comment: btw is info in this case an array?

Comment: no, "`info`" is a NSDictionary, which contains objects or values and the keys that associate with them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can iterate through everything in the dictionary:

```
NSArray *dictionaryKeys = [info allKeys];
for (NSString *key in dictionaryKeys) {
    // Do something with info[key]
}
```